# Optimal trade-off between oversampling and filter length

Tags: filters, interpolation, resampling, gradient

For some sampling-frequency-preserving operations on Nyquist–Shannon sampled signals, such as:

- a **shift** a.k.a. **translation**, and
- **differentiation** by applying a **derivative filter** a.k.a. **gradient filter**,

the ideal filter for each task has an infinite number of taps with weights obtained by [sampling the sinc function or its derivative](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/44009/15347). In practice, **finite-impulse-response** (FIR) approximations are typically used.

For a given maximum acceptable level of approximation error, the required minimum number of taps in the approximating FIR filter is reduced if there is an overhead $f_B\ldots f_s/2$ between the highest frequency $f_B$ of the signal and half the sampling frequency $f_s$. From filter design perspective, this overhead obtained by **oversampling** the input signal by a factor $\beta = f_s/(2f_B) > 1$ creates a transition band of non-zero width and relaxes requirements on the filter, as exemplified by the magnitude frequency response of a [simple approximative derivative filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/27430/15347) decipted in Fig. 1.

[image]
*Figure 1. Arbitrarily normalized magnitude frequency response of an ideal derivative filter (diagonal red line) and its approximation (black curve) with impulse response $-3/16,$ $31/32,$ $0,$ $-31/32,$ $3/16$. With ideal oversampling, the frequency response above the highest frequency of the signal (vertical blue line) does not contribute to the approximation error.*

However, assuming that the output signal is sampled at the same sampling frequency $f_s$ as the input signal, increasing $f_s$ increases the number of output samples, which increases the number of times a dot product between the $N$ filter weights and $N$ signal samples needs to be calculated. In general, for a 1-d signal, $\beta N$ times as many **multiply–accumulate operations** (MACs) are needed compared to the number of samples in critically sampled (not oversampled) representation of the input and output signals.

**For such a task, which oversampling factor $\beta$ minimizes $\beta N$, requiring the least total MACs in FIR filtering without exceeding a given maximum acceptable approximation error measured by a reasonable error metric?**

Upsampling to obtain the oversampled input signal shall be considered ideal and not contributing to the MAC count, as if the input signal was obtained perfectly pre-oversampled.

Comment: Do you mean "upsampling" (i.e interpolation) rather than "oversampling" (increasing sampling rate)?  Also, when you say "ideal filter", I wouldn't be so quick to crown the "bandlimited" as best.  For differentiation(s), polynomial interpolations may be better.  Differentiation is inherently a local operation.

Comment: @CedronDawg "Oversampling" tastes better to me because it gives a desired indication of there being a continuous band-limited signal of which the samples give a representation, and the *process of* upsampling needs not be considered for this question. See [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44007/derivative-filter-in-python/44009#44009) (also linked to in the question) about derivative filtering of [Nyquist–Shannon sampled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) signals.

Comment: I double checked before I asked.  Here is one source: https://www.audioholics.com/audio-technologies/upsampling-vs-oversampling-for-digital-audio  With interpolation, the "more points" takes on a different meaning.

Comment: @CedronDawg [invoking r b-j](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266675823_Performance_of_Low-Order_Polynomial_Interpolators_in_the_Presence_of_Oversampled_Input) on "oversampling". I added one "upsamping" to the question.

Comment: I think you and R B-J may be in the minority.  Undersampling/Oversampling and Downsampling/Upsampling/Resampling seem to refer to the actual sampling rate for the former and interpolation for the latter in all references I found.  Unfortunately I don't have time to work on this right now, but will accept the premise of the question to be about a bandlimited noiseless signal where upsampling and oversampling would be equivalent.  I also see you've done considerable work already on the related "Pyhon" question.

Answer (score 2):

### 1-d MMSE derivative filter for uniform spectral prior

With some simplifying assumptions about the signal distribution, a filter with least square frequency response error is the Bayesian minimum mean square error (MMSE) filter for a uniform prior of the frequency spectrum. For such 1-d filters, an oversampling factor $\beta \approx 2\ldots2.5$ seems optimal, as it is in the sweet spot of the cost-benefit curves (Fig. 1).

[image]
*Figure 1. Mean square frequency response error of [least square optimal derivative filters](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/44009/15347) as function of computational complexity as measured by $\beta N$ which is proportional to the total number of multiply-accumulates (MACs), for various oversampling factors $\beta$ for which the filters have been optimized. Also shown are traces for different numbers $N$ of non-zero filter coefficients. No advantage was taken from impulse response anti-symmetry or simple coefficients such as $1$.*

More data is needed before general conclusions can be drawn.